# Storing multiple images and displaying them within large bodies of text

Tags: database, image, elasticsearch, architecture, storage

We currently have a million academic documents that need to be stored in a database. These documents contain text and figures (images) that are used to illustrate some concept within a specific section.

We have managed to separate the text and store it in our choice of Database which is ElasticSearch. However, we are unsure of how to proceed with storing the images available per document, retrieving them and displaying them most importantly in between the correct paragraphs.

Therefore I am looking for advice on the best approach for storing many images that should be embedded in bodies of text. What approach is high performance? Looking forward to hear from your experiences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML does this rather well... Kind of designed for it...  No need to reinvent anything here.  Dump them to a folder per-document, put  tags in with URLs in the text to reference them.  Static web sites scale rather well :-)

Comment: Does that mean when i am creating the JSON format for the document, i store the image, take the location path and insert it into the JSON output like so? { paragraph: "hello", imgpath: "/server1/world.png", paragraph: "!" }. Where in between paragraph hello and !, the image world belongs in the right place.

Comment: I would just make it more along the lines of paragraph: "hello <img src=\"\/server1\/world.png\"\/>!".  do you really need the data structured with them as separate bits?  If you want, you could make it a templated solution, paragraph: "hello <<img1>>!", img1="/server1/world.png", but if you don't need them separate, I'd combine them.

Comment: Ah i understand, for the sake of future proofing, we decided that a separate line for the images as i proposed would allow us to display images in a list on a separate tab, additionally ElasticSearch search similarity algorithms will not apply to the included image text within paragraphs. So at the end of the day, is it really as easy as that? Do we just need to code a script that integrates our file-system paths into the text JSON format? Let me know if this is often the case, would be happy to confirm as answer :)